# Adding a dict from a list into another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list that contains dictionary's and I want to add every third entry in that list into a new one
The list looks like this:

```
result = [{"link": "example.com", "text": "Some description"}, {"link": "example2.com", "text": "lorem ipsum"}] ...
```

Right now the loop I have  looks like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(list), 3):
    cleanresults.extend(list[i])
```

but instead of copying the whole list it only adds the keys

```
["link", "text", "link", "text"]
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: to add an element into the list, use `append()` instead of `extend()`

Comment: `extend` takes an iterable, which `list[i]` (a `dict`) is; as an iterable, you just get the keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to **append**, not extend:

```
for i in range(0, len(list), 3):
    cleanresults.append(list[i])
```

Extending adds the *contained* elements from the object you passed in; when you iterate over a dictionary you get keys, so those are then added to the `cleanresults` list, not the dictionary itself.

More cleanly, you could just create a copy of the original list taking every 3rd element with a [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-slice-notation):

```
cleanresults = list[::3]
```

If you didn't want a copy, but only needed to access every third element while iterating, you could also use an [`itertools.islice()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice

for every_third in islice(list, 0, None, 3):
    # do something with every third dictionary.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
result = [{"link": "example.com", "text": "Some description"}, {"link": "example2.com", "text": "lorem ipsum"}] ...

new_result = result[::3] #this list slicing will take every third element in the result list
```

Output:

```
[{'text': 'Some description', 'link': 'example.com'}]
```